# Keyboard will show notification does not work when i click on textview twice

Tags: swift, uitextview, nsnotificationcenter, uikeyboard

I have a textview at the top of screen and a custom view like a toolbar at the bottom of the screen. When the user clicks on the textview the keyboard appears and the toolbar goes up with the keyboard. Then I have a dismiss button on the toolbar that call the endediting func on the textview. When I click on the textview a second time, the toolbar does not appear but I need it to appear. This is the code I have attached to my custom toolbar that makes it move up:

```
extension UIView{
func bindToKeyboard(){
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: NSNotification){

    let duration = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
    let curve = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! UInt
    let beginningFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let endFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let deltaY = endFrame.origin.y - beginningFrame.origin.y



    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: curve), animations: {

        if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height == 2436 {//check user device
            //iPhone X
             self.frame.origin.y += deltaY + 35
        }else{
             self.frame.origin.y += deltaY
        }

    }, completion: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: NSNotification){
    let duration = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
    let curve = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! UInt
    let beginningFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let endFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let deltaY = endFrame.origin.y - beginningFrame.origin.y



    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: curve), animations: {

        if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height == 2436 {//check user device
            //iPhone X

            self.frame.origin.y = 0
        }else{
            self.frame.origin.y = 0
        }

    }, completion: nil)
}
}
```

This is the code I have for my textview when the keyboard appears:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.editView.bindToKeyboard()

   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}



@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0)
            textView.contentInset = contentInsets
        }
    }

@objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: NSNotification) {

        let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        textView.contentInset = contentInsets

}
```

Comment: maybe save the frame of the keyboard then load it again in viewDidLayoutSubviews(). <That function will be called every time u tap on a textfield.

Answer (score 0):

For Keyboard showing state, use UIKeyboardWillShowNotification.

```
   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(keyboardWillShow) , name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
```